# How to dispose or close an instance of XML Document in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

There's a problem, wherein a XML Document.Save is resulting in the error the process cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process or the statement an Invalid XML Document.I think it's because I do not dispose the XML Document object after it's operation is complete.Is it possible to do this.Is there a workaround?

Comment: How are you accessing it now, can you post the code

Comment: you must post some code so that one can get some idea about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which overload of the [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save.aspx) method you are using. If you pass directly a filename as string there shouldn't be issues. If you pass a stream or xmlwriter you need to ensure that it is properly disposed:

```
using (Stream stream = ...)
{
    doc.Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: It seems that I have an issue, maybe you can tell me what it is:
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(new FileStream(this.FilePath, FileMode.Create), xwSettings))
   {
    XmlDocument.WriteTo(xw);
   }

This code seems not work because if I try to load the same file direct after that I get the exception "Is already in use"

Answer (score 3):

XmlDocument, as well as the newer XDocument, are in-memory representations of an XML document, so you don't need to close them.

Perhaps you are using an underlying `Stream` or similar to read the documents, and that is what needs to be closed ? Without more context, it is almost impossible to answer.