# Exception during xml processing

Tags: c#, .net, exception, io

I'm just referring back to my question here (not yet resolved):

[c# Exception The process cannot access the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811093/c-sharp-exception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file)

The exception is not happening when I'm running in Debug mode, it's only doing it when I'm running from the exe.

Can someone put a reason to it, why it's giving the exception when running the exe and not in debug mode.

The first time I run the exe, it works successfully and give's me the xml output I need. But for the second find for the watcher. It give me this exception: The process cannot access the file.

Comment: If you dont need to write to the xml file itself, in its original form, you can try opening it as a ReadOnly/shared filestream and then loading the XmlDocument object from there, rather than using the XmlDocument base, which might not give you as many options...

Comment: @Nevyn: I'm using XMLDocument to validate if the XML if perfect, if not I use a catch to add the missing tags, because sometimes I get the xml without those missing tags as you can see in the catch right after the xdoc XMLDOCUMENT. Is there any other way to do it

Comment: Im not saying to use something other than XmlDocument, Im saying to open the file using FileStream originally...which gives you more options like ReadOnly and/or Shared, then load the XmlDocument from the FileStream.  This might let you get around the initial problem.  Now, you still have the issue with malformed xml and having to repair the original file, but that can be taken care of once we get the first issue fixed.  One thing at a time :-)

Comment: @user726720 +1 for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look over that complete code set....the issue you are having has to do with events and timing.  Your event is firing from the FileWatcher object before whatever process is saving the file lets it go.  Try putting a Thread.Sleep right at the top of the Convert method...doesn't need to be too long, start with maybe 1 second or so...see what happens.

```
    private static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
    {
        string FileName;
        FileName = f.FullPath;
        string FilePath;
        FilePath = f.Name;
                 var watcher = source as FileSystemWatcher;
             string destinationFile = @"D:/GS/" + FilePath;

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        //...
```

Comment: Yes, sweet, it works. along with the monitor snippet from Luke Marlin below

Comment: @Nevyn So +1 for your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have made your lock wrong, and therefore multiple threads try to get your file

Try to do as follows:

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
{
    try{
    //Your actual code
    }
}
else
    return;
```

Comment: sure, let me try that.

Comment: nope bro, it's the same: the process cannot access the file. I have been trying to figure this out for a week now, no results so far

Comment: Have you tried to close your xdoc instead of setting it to null ? In debug mode, GC may have the time to collect it because of the breakpoints. With direct exe, there is no pause and no GC call are done on time

Comment: ok @user726720 just i have one idea, go to the properties of the folder and add everyone and give all permissions to that. then check it.

Comment: @LukeMarlin: The only way I know of it and have learned it from previous threads is setting xdoc=null should do the job, others have suggested there is no need for that. Do you know of a better way how to close xdoc. Please advise

Comment: @RJK: Nope doesn't work I have set everyone to this folder and set permissions as full control. It's the same. I believe it's not related to permissions, because the first I run the exe it works the first time. But with the second find for the watcher it gives the exception

Comment: @user726720 You should probably say this in your question.

Comment: @user726720 ok. Go to Task Manager and stop your **EXE** process and re run your exe again. If its running. check under process tab.

Comment: @LukeMarlin: Sorry about missing that. I will edit it now. Thank you.

Comment: @user726720 I updated my answer, give it a try please

Comment: @RJK: Have done that a number of times now. Did again as per your suggestion. After executing it fresh it runs fine for the first find, but gives an exception on the second find and there after

Comment: @user726720 Ya because your exe is not getting stopped. EXE is getting continuous communication with the XML. That is why the file access problem is coming.

Comment: @LukeMarlin: Have tried your suggestion for the lock as above. It doesn't help

Comment: @RJK: "exe is not getting stopped". I don't understand that.

Comment: @user726720 you need to cross check your code. its running continuously.

Comment: @user726720 Can you please show me the complete code that include my suggestion so I can see it please ?

Comment: @user726720 I mean the process of your exe. Under the Process tab you can check it, in task manager.

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/zKLQSPQj

Comment: That's what I thought, you misunderstood my snippet. The `TryEnter` statement I gave you was meant to replace yours. You was not supposed to add it elsewhere

Comment: @user726720 Like this : http://pastebin.com/1bFJS7z6

Comment: Here goes another one: http://pastebin.com/xHGrcRzV. Please check this one

Comment: Yup, if your lock is in the first `if` statement like this, no other thread could go in and raise the exception. Is it working ?

Comment: It's working now but there has to be a thread.sleep that needs to go with this lock snippet. I will post the final solution here soon

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27637/discussion-between-luke-marlin-and-user726720)

Comment: @LukeMarlin +1 for your answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Your **EXE** process is running continuously. The process of your exe should be stopped probably. Then "The Process cannot Access the file" error will never come. Use proper Error handling techniques to your codes. Your code has continuous communications with the XML file. So, if you try to access second time, the access error is coming if i'm not wrong.

Comment: +1 for helping me out.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final convert() that works properly. Thanks to all of you who have helped me here. I really appreciate your time and effort in helping me out. I wish I could accept both the solutions above. But I'm giving my vote to both of you. Thank you once again.

```
private static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
{
    string FileName;
    FileName = f.FullPath;
    string FilePath;
    FilePath = f.Name;
    var watcher = source as FileSystemWatcher;
    string destinationFile = @"D:/GS/" + FilePath;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject)) **
    {
        try
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                xdoc.Load(FileName);
                xdoc = null;
            }
            catch (XmlException xe)
            {
                xdoc = null;
                using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(FileName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(xe);
                    w.WriteLine("</title>");
                    w.WriteLine("</titleContent>");
                    Console.WriteLine("1st");
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(new StreamReader(FileName, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256")));
            XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
            myXslTrans.Load("D:/GS/xsl/test.xsl");
            XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(destinationFile, null);
            myWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            myWriter.Indentation = 4;
            myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);
            myWriter.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("2nd");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Finally");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

}